# Parliament2 fails with 'Unknown options: --only-show-errors' when running with Nextflow

Tags: docker, aws-batch, nextflow

Nextflow attempts to stage its script to the docker container using an `aws s3 cp` command that includes the `--only-show-errors` option.  Unfortunately, the parliament2 docker container uses an old version of the aws cli that does not have that option.

I would like to understand exactly what is happening and how to resolve it.

First:
Strangely, I don't see any aws cli on the parliament container, so I'm not sure how it is even finding an old version.

I looked into the container by first doing `docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash  dnanexus/parliament2`.  Then, once inside the container, I ran `which aws`, but did not see anything.

If I run the container with AWS Batch and perform the same `which aws` command it shows one in `/usr/bin/aws`.

I also checked `docker inspect dnanexus/parliament2` but don't see any code in the entrypoint or cmd that could be installing the aws cli.

**Why is an old version of the cli present when running the container in Batch but not when I run the container locally?**

Second, how can I resolve the situation.  I thought about installing the current aws cli on the host image and then mounting it in the container and setting PATH to include the new mountpoint as an environmental variable in the container.  Would that work?  I experimented briefly with this but did not feel like it was respecting my PATH variable.

Comment: Couple notes: Nextflow has a very active user community on Slack, which you may get more milage out of. It even has a [channel for AWS questions](https://nextflow.slack.com/archives/C02T97HAV5M)

Second, how are you setting up and running NF on AWS?  E.g. Are you using [Tower](https://cloud.tower.nf/) or something else? It is highly likely that the process set up Batch to use a specific AMI with the old version of the AWS CLI and the Batch job definition has a host volume mount that is in the PATH.